# VisualStudio 2010 Cannot load class diagram "Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class-diagram

In a VisualStudio 2010 solution with many projects one of the projects contains some class diagrams. When I try to open them I get the error message `Cannot load '<class diagram file>': Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.`

Besides googling (I only found solutions for some different problems) I tried the following things:

- removed some and all class diagram content: got the same error
- added a new class diagram to the project: got the same error
- created a new solution & project, and added a new class diagram: it worked!
- created a new solution and added the existing project with the class diagrams: it worked!
- deleted SUO and SDF file: got the same error

Any idea how I can fix my solution? Creating a new solution would be possible, but tedious, and I would risk to encounter the same problem again. Because the solution is copy right protected and massive I cannot provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Follow these steps:

- Go to Project » Properties.
- Click on Framework And References.
- Remove all the references.

Answer (score 2):

In the properties of the project remove the reference under the Framework And References branch

Comment: The answer is identical to the above one and worked (+1), but less detailed.

Answer (score 1):

In the project properties, under Framework and References, remove all references that point to non-existent libraries. (marked with a red X)

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by an invalid reference.

1. Project > Properties
2. Common Properties > Frameworks and References
3. Locate your invalid references; they are marked with a red line in the GUI and may result in a build warning like "The referenced project '......\foo.vcxproj' does not exist."
   [image: remove invalid reference]
4. Class diagrams now load without error

Other answers suggest removing *all* references, but you probably only need to remove invalid ones.